# Confused with amcl map to odom transform

Tags: localization, navigation, transforms, ros-melodic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) for localizing my robot in Gazebo in a known map. My robot has an IMU and a laser on it.

I was going through the amcl docs and I noticed this.

```
Published Topics 
...
tf (tf/tfMessage) 
Publishes the transform from odom (which can be remapped via the ~odom_frame_id parameter) to map.
```

According to [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), both odom & map are world fixed frames. So why does amcl publish a transform from map to odom? Shouldn't this transform be static?

**Note**: Although it is not relevant to this question, but if you are wondering - I am generating the odometry data using package robot_localization, which takes as input the IMU data. amcl requires odometry and laser scan data to localize the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300999/confused-with-amcl-map-to-odom-transform/) by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 512 on 2018-08-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think now I understand why amcl publishes the map to odom transform. This is explained in the [Transforms section of the amcl documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Transforms). Reproducing it here with the relevant emphasis:

> amcl transforms incoming laser scans to the odometry frame (~odom_frame_id). So there must exist a path through the tf tree from the frame in which the laser scans are published to the odometry frame.
>
> An implementation detail: **on receipt of the first laser scan, amcl looks up the transform between the laser's frame and the base frame (~base_frame_id)**, and **latches it forever**. So amcl cannot handle a laser that moves with respect to the base.
>
> The drawing below shows the difference between localization using odometry and amcl. During operation amcl estimates the transformation of the base frame (~base_frame_id) in respect to the global frame (~global_frame_id) but it only publishes the transform between the global frame and the odometry frame (~odom_frame_id). **Essentially, this transform accounts for the drift that occurs using Dead Reckoning**.

[image: image description]

Additionally these posts also helped me cement this understanding:

1. [How to broadcast a transform between /map and /odom](https://answers.ros.org/question/44639/how-to-broadcast-a-transform-between-map-and-odom/?answer=44645#post-id-44645)
2. [transform base_link to base_laser,map,odom](https://answers.ros.org/question/10658/transform-base_link-to-base_lasermapodom/?answer=15727#post-id-15727)

So to summarize:

1. Both odom and map are world fixed frames
2. However the pose in odom frame will drift due to dead reckoning
3. To fix this you publish a map to odom transform, which essentially fixes the pose of the robot in the map frame.

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 512 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5